# DDMathParser: How to define default values for variables

Tags: ios, objective-c, parsing, nsdictionary, nspredicate

I am using `DDMathParser` to parse formulas and calculate the results, which works great.

**Question:**

Is it possible to set variables to default values in case they do not exist in the substitution dictionary?

**Example:**

My formula `$a + $b` requires two variables `$a` and `$b`. However, my substitution dictionary contains only an value for variable key `a` (e.g. 1), but does not contain an key `b`.

What would be the preferred way to define variable `b` to be `0` as default value and avoid the parsing error message `"unable to resolve variable"`?

Thank you!

### Edit

The way I am using `DDMathParser` is by looping over multiple formulas and providing the same variable substitution dictionary to each formula. Sometimes, I don't have values for the variables: In this case the variables (keys and values) would not be included in the dictionary.

Depending on the formula itself, I would like to return `nil` as result for the formula if one of the variables does not exist (e.g. I don't have a value for `profit` and the formula is `$profit / $revenue`, I would like to return `nil` which I can convert to a `NSString` of `n/a` later) or set the variable to `0` if it is does not exist in the dictionary (e.g. for a formula like `$profitA + $profitB + $profitC`, I would like to assume `0` for any missing variables (`$profitA`, `$profitB` or `$profitC`).

For this reason, I cannot use a generic solution, which always returns `0` or `nil`, but would need to put this logic in the formula (e.g. as a custom function).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DDMathParser author here.

> Is it possible to set variables to default values in case they do not exist in the substitution dictionary?

Kind of.  You could do it by supplying a `variableResolver` block to the math evaluator:

```
DDMathEvaluator *evaluator = [DDMathEvaluator sharedMathEvaluator];
[evaluator setVariableResolver:^(NSString *variable) { return @0; }];
NSNumber *n = [evaluator evaluateString:myString withSubstitutions:mySubstitutions];
```

The variable resolver block gets executed whenever the evaluator comes across a variable that it can't find in the substitutions dictionary.

> Would it be feasible to add a custom function to DDMathParser like defaultZero($b) which retrieves the variable b if it exists or zero if not?

Hm, clever idea.  You could, but you would essentially by mimicking the behavior of the variableResolver block.  You'd create a new `DDMathFunction` block and use the `-[DDMathEvaluator registerFunction:forName:]` to tell the evaluator about it.

However, I'd recommend just supplying a variable resolver block.  It'd be much simpler.

---

Here's how you'd define a `defaultZero` function that returns either the value of the argument or `0` (if the argument can't be evaluated):

```
DMathEvaluator *evaluator = [DDMathEvaluator sharedMathEvaluator];
[evaluator registerFunction:^DDExpression *(NSArray *args, NSDictionary *vars, DDMathEvaluator *eval, NSError *__autoreleasing *error) {
    NSNumber *argValue = nil;
    if ([args count] == 1) {
        // defaultZero() only supports a single argument
        // for anything else, return 0
        DDExpression *arg = [args objectAtIndex:0];
        NSError *argError = nil;
        argValue = [eval evaluateExpression:arg withSubstitutions:vars error:&argError];
    }

    if (argValue == nil) {
        // return 0 if either the arg can't be eval'd or there isn't 1 arg
        argValue = @0;
    }
    return [DDExpression numberExpressionWithNumber:argValue];

} forName:@"defaultZero"];
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Dave! I have updated my question and tried to describe that I need to return either `nil` if one of the variables is missing or set the default to `0`. The logic for this should be set in the formula. This is I why I am thinking that a custom function might be better suitable in this case. However, I don't fully understand on how I would need to do this in a custom function (I have read [DDMathParser Wiki](https://github.com/davedelong/DDMathParser/wiki/Adding-New-Functions) but still do not fully understand how to code this). Do you have any suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: @AlexR I've updated the answer with an example of how to define a `defaultZero` function.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much for your support and for creating `DDMathParser`.

Answer (score 3):

Initialize the substitution dictionary with appropriate default values first, then update it with any actual values.

Comment: Would it be feasible to add a custom function to `DDMathParser` like `defaultZero($b)`which retrieves the variable `b` if it exists or zero if not?

Comment: @AlexR Since you have the code, you can make any changes you wish. Adding logic to use zero for a missing variable should be easy enough if that is what you want to do.